# fatal Error Message with thread 1: Exc_breakpoint

Tags: swift

I am trying to open my app on my Ipad 2, and it's giving me an error

thread 1:exc_breakpoint (code=exc_arm_breakpoint, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
and on the button it says

specialiazed_fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, file: StaticString, line: UInt, flags: UInt32) ->Never

it's breaking on the viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    className.text = allNotes[currentNoteindex].name
    tview.text = allNotes[currentNoteindex].note
    className.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

any help will be highy grateful

Comment: Please provide more information. The question, in its current state, is unclear. You mentioned a button but the question doesn't mention anything else about it. Also, you haven't provided the context to your `viewDidLoad` method. Please clearly state what have you tried so far? What is the expected outcome?. For further information, please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Xcode -> window->Projects then select and delete your project derived data. try this

Comment: @iOSGeek Well I checked there is no Projects under window, so I really don't what to do now

Comment: @Malik the main problem is `currentNoteIndex` excuse my English I didn't mean "button" I meant bottom very sorry for that.  well I have tried to convert the `(int) currentNoteIndex` to `Unint32(currentNoteIndex)` but that didn't work. I tried `allNotes[Int(Unint32(currentNoteIndex))]` but that didn't work too. The whole projects works on iPhone 5,6, and 7 perfectly; it just doesn't work on my IPad 2 which is on IOS 9.3 ( and I also reduce the target for my project to target IOS 9.3 but that didn't solve it ). I would appreciate any help

Comment: are you using `arc4random()` anywhere in your project?

Comment: Nop. I am not using it

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it why did you get such issue because I had never got such issue try following methods please

1) Are you using some Nsuserdefault or any value that is required please check If value is nil

2) Check your storyboard file and constraints

3)in project Settings - > Deployment info -> Devices to universal [Check it must not be to iPhone only]

4) get latest version of Xcode and iPhone OS.

5) Using iOS 10 try downgrade to older version

6) check rest o your code initialise breakpoints[image]